# query modification for graphical data

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc

I am working on spring mvc application, in which I need to illustrate the graphical data of salary per month wise, I am using high charts for this, in high charts we need to specify the series'

I decide to pick series like
for each month
Gross Earn,
Gross Deduction,
and Net Pay

I have already service ready which display the monthwise counts,
but I just want a series of month, I want a modification in my exisiting query so I can bind all the three series in sing object.

this is java code of service which is currently fetches only the count.

```
 public AttOfficerDashboardDTO getDashboardCount(final String yearMonth, String refId) {
        String query = "SELECT   "
                + "Count(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID) tot_emp,  "
                + "SUM(NET_SALARY)net_salary,  "
                + "SUM(GROSS_EARNING) gross_earn,  "
                + "SUM(GROSS_DEDUCTION)gros_deduct    "
                + "FROM EMPLOYEE_SALARY_SUMMARY  "
                + "WHERE REFERENCE_ID= :REFERENCE_ID  "
                + "AND YEAR_MONTH= :YEAR_MONTH "; 
        MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        param.addValue("YEAR_MONTH", yearMonth);
        param.addValue("REFERENCE_ID", refId);
        AttOfficerDashboardDTO dto = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(query, param, new RowMapper<AttOfficerDashboardDTO>() {
            @Override
            public AttOfficerDashboardDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
                AttOfficerDashboardDTO dto = new AttOfficerDashboardDTO();
                dto.setTotEmp(rs.getInt("tot_emp"));
                dto.setGrossEarning(rs.getDouble("gross_earn"));
                dto.setGrossDeduction(rs.getDouble("gros_deduct"));
                dto.setGrossDeduction(rs.getDouble("gros_deduct"));
                dto.setNetPay(rs.getDouble("net_salary"));
                dto.setYearMonth(yearMonth);
                return dto;
            }
        });
        return dto;
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) tot_emp,
    SUM(net_salary) net_salary,
    SUM(gross_earning) gross_earn,
    SUM(gross_deduction) gros_deduct
FROM
    employee_salary_summary
WHERE
        reference_id =:reference_id
    AND
        year_month =:year_month
```

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can help you with the vague question. What type of chart are your trying to create? And in most charts you will need to have three separate series, one for each data type you want to display. From what I get you want to display 3 different types of data in one graph, so 3 series would be normal,

Comment: I am trying to create bar chart

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic